# Access all the photos of user album in iphone using application

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, slideshow, photo-gallery, image-archive

I am working on one application in which i need to show slide show of the user selected photo album,
UIImagePickerController only returns the selected image. I want all previous and next images of the selected image, is it possible with UIImagePickerController and if not is there any other way that i can do it.
Thanks in advance,
Satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom picker to select an album instead of an image. You'll want to use ALAssetLibrary to get a list of albums via enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock and then on the group call enumerateAssetsUsingBlock: to get the individual images.