# How to iterate through all images in photos folder and load them into an NSMutable array?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible for me to put all the images in my photos folder into a NSMutableArray as UIImages?  If so, how could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to get the images from the photos from the photos folder on the device. There are great associated sample projects from Apple which are easily found from a google search.

**EDIT:** If you need to grab more then just a user selected photo, you can use the `ALAssetLibrary` and `Blocks`. There are some similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002657/access-all-the-photos-of-user-album-in-iphone-using-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468496/how-to-get-all-images-in-iphone-photo-album) which point you in the right direction. I would also look at [Block Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) if you are new to Blocks, as this will help you grasp what is going on. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question.  I meant to ask if there was a way for me to put all the images into an array without having to physically click all of them with the UIImagePickerController, because I need to put around 100 images in this array.

Comment: I'll start looking at these posts and links. Thanks for the help!